# Replacing wordpress blog post images markup with custom div

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The images that are posted on a wordpress blog gets marked up as,

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large">
 <img src="http://localhost/ela/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/MG_5512_23.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-541" srcset="http://localhost/ela/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/MG_5512_23.jpg 683w, http://localhost/ela/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/MG_5512_23-200x300.jpg 200w" sizes="(max-width: 683px) 100vw, 683px">
</figure>
```

I'd like to have the images encased in the following structure;

```
<div class="img-box">
 <div class="item loaded">
   <img src="http://localhost/ela/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/07_40.jpg" data-src="http://localhost/ela/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/07_40.jpg" alt="title">
 </div>
</div>
```

I found this question
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36000/wrap-all-post-images-inside-a-div-element  but I wasn't able to form the required regex to achieve what I want. The code which I have tried from the article is,

```
function breezer_addDivToImage( $content ) {

   // A regular expression of what to look for.
   $pattern = '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i';
   // What to replace it with. $1 refers to the content in the first 'capture group', in parentheses above
   $replacement = '<div class="myphoto">$1</div>';

   // run preg_replace() on the $content
   $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );

   // return the processed content
   return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'breezer_addDivToImage' );
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: @disinfor, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36000/wrap-all-post-images-inside-a-div-element i have tried this amongst other, i am not able to figure out the regex for my case though.

Comment: Can you please add the code from that to your question? If that link goes dead, this question will be useless to future visitors.

Comment: @disinfor, done.